# What would be the correct variable name?

Tags: c, naming

In a implementation for a real time embedded device, I have a status register variable for each channel (let's blindly assume my embedded device have multiple channels and some work has to be done for each of them).

So here's how the status variable is currently declared:

```
struct channel_status status[NCHANNELS];
```

Matter of performance, it is better to use an intermediate global variable that is the copy of the `status` variable for the selected channel.

Example:

```
struct channel_status status_shadow;

void some_work() {
    for(channel = 0; channel < NCHANNELS; channel++) {
        status_shadow = status[channel]; 
        foo(); // Function that use the status_shadow as global
        bar(); // "
        baz(); // "
        status[channel] = status_shadow;
}
```

Am I not discussing the implementation neither the possibility to use a pointer instead of a variable. My question is related to the name of the intermediate variable.

I chose `status_shadow` because I think I am doing some kind of [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

> Is there a better/more accurate *technical* name for such intermediate variable ?

#### Implementation considerations:

The reason why I decided to use this intermediate variable is because it is too resource consuming to pass either the channel pointer `i` or the status variable to each function `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, ... In terms of performance avoiding stack push/pop can save some precious time in real-time applications.

Comment: You are not shadowing anything, IMO. Your approach is simply round robin. I suggest `status_selected` or similar.

Comment: I like `status_shadow`, it was immediately clear what you were doing. A possibly related term is "working set", which might have been a better name if it was an actual set of variables.

Comment: OT: Copying the `struct` would also take time. Wether this is few then pushing a pointer value on the stack a few times might be a subject to discuss.

Comment: `current_status, active_status`? I don't see shadowing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not technically shadowing; you would have to define a variable of the same **name** to shadow it. Moreover, shadowing is generally frowned upon because careless use could lead to easy confusion.

What you are doing is taking the **current item** for your cycle, so a suited name could be `current_status` or `cur_status`. If you used it as a parameter, so the name would be only contained into the `for()`, it could have been `current` or `cur_item` as well.

Another idea could be `temp_channel_status`, implying that the value is not to be considered fixed albeit the variable is global.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `status_local`, or `status_local_copy`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like a name such as `work_status` or `status_copy`.